# (Overleaf and LuaLaTeX) ы with acute stress only works correctly sometimes (using Times New Roman and STIX Two Text) [Not A Repost]

Tags: babel, hyphenation, accents, cyrillic, russian

I posted a semi similar question a while ago where I asked about why the ы character did not appear correctly **at all** on TNR with the acute accent when using `\'ы`. I have a Chromebook and have downloaded the (seemingly) latest version (7.05) of Times New Roman, which also looks to be the same versions that Windows 11 uses, since the version I have now supports small caps and more glyphs that didnt work before for me.

With TNR 7.05, when using `\ы`, it will sometimes have the accent put in the right spot, but when using it in a sentence, it seems to not work. It has the right position in the first part of my example, but I'm not sure why its so unconsistent. This doesn't only apply to TNR, since in my example, STIX Two Text is also affected.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont[BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
    \newfontfamily\secondfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
\'ы ы́ 
}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), they sound like A.

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{{\secondfont Б\'ыло}}), they sound like A.

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
ф\'ыф
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that if you have Windows, my `\setmainfont` code should work regardless of if you have downloaded the files for the TNR variants through the web or somewhere else.

Its weird that it will look different depending on where it is placed, can someone please help with this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708196/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i added the windows version to my overleaf setup by looking up the latest version online. That works even on a chromebook. That's why I have different code.

Comment: Well, I don't own/have windows, so it wouldn't be a problem, right? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle asked about the font license. That is not a silly comment, it is important. Many fonts that come with a system or softwar may only be used with that system or software, and perhaps may not be used in digital publications (only print to paper).

Comment: @rallg if I found it online and its not taking profits away (TNR IS free on windows, after all), then I should be able to use it. I dont plan to make any material using it for profit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't see an issue with me not having a licence if I don't profit from using the font

Comment: @FelixMaldonado That's not the way some font licenses work. In some cases, it matters whether or not you are using it for profit. In other cases, it does not matter: Any usage outside the operating system or software is prohibited. In those cases, the font is considered to be a component of the system or software, so if you use the font elsewhere, it would be like using the system or software without a license. I do not know about the specific font (because there are clones). Might be OK for TNR.

Comment: I guess millions of people using Google docs and word owe monotype their TNR debt then @DavidCarlisle

Comment: And? They can be used for free. The font is free.  It makes no difference if I use what I'm using and what they are.

Comment: I contacted the company and a support person told me it is ok as long as I use TNR for non commercial use. The licence for TNR by Monotype conflicts with the general windows fonts licence in some other ways as well. The website you linked itself also says I have extended rights. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative approach, which has the advantage hyphenation points aren’t dropped (sadly, `HarfBuzz` in hyphenated languages doesn’t always work as expected). It’s based on a transform:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont
     [BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
    \newfontfamily\secondfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel} 

% Add this transform, which removes discretionaries
% before combining characters:
\babelposthyphenation{russian}{ |[{0300}-{036F}] }{ remove, {} }

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
\'ы ы́ 
}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), they sound like A.

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{{\secondfont Б\'ыло}}), they sound like A.

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
ф\'ыф
}

\end{document}
```

Of course, it’s just a workaround. It gives:
[image]

Comment: seeing this suggested an alternative of adjusting the patterns rather than post processing the resulting list (I posted an answer)

Comment: @JavierBezos I honestly feel overloaded with the two options that you and David provided, is there a use case for one and another? Is yours better?

Comment: @FelixMaldonado Mine is more general. It works in your case and in many others (including Greek and Latin scripts), at the cost of a (very small) speed penalty. Davis’s is ad hoc: it works in your case, but if you also use, say, the combining diaeresis, then the corresponding pattern must be added. Which is better is relative.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is hyphenation, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340164/2388
and https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/267.

The issue should really be resolved generally. Until then if you use the harfbuzz-Renderer the problem disappears:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont
     [Renderer=Harfbuzz,BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
    \newfontfamily\secondfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
\'ы ы́ 
}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), they sound like A.

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{{\secondfont Б\'ыло}}), they sound like A.

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
ф\'ыф
}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can add a pattern to prevent hyphenation before the combining character as shown below the rule in this example

A better babel interface, to be used in the preamble would be

```
\babelpatterns[russian]{8^^^^0301}
```

But here, just in the test example, I use a lower level `\patterns` form so I can demonstrate with and without this pattern switching mid document.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont
     [BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
    \newfontfamily\secondfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel} 

% Add this transform, which removes discretionaries
% before combining characters:
%\babelposthyphenation{russian}{ |[{0300}-{036F}] }{ remove, {} }

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
\'ы ы́ 
}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), they sound like A.

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{{\secondfont Б\'ыло}}), they sound like A.

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
ф\'ыф
}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
  \patterns{8^^^^0301}
}


\foreignlanguage{russian}{
\'ы ы́ 
}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), they sound like A.

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{{\secondfont Б\'ыло}}), they sound like A.

\foreignlanguage{russian}{
ф\'ыф
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another option, indeed (and faster), provided `9` is not used and the pattern doesn’t exist (fortunately, that's not the case). There is a command in `babel` to (re)define patterns: `\babelpatterns[russian]{8^^^^0301}`. If the pattern exists, it gets replaced.

Comment: @JavierBezos ah thanks I thought there would be, I'll change to use that. Yes it's a shame the highest even number isn't quite high enough but it is what it is:-) (presumably the standard patterns could have such a clause for all combining accents?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hate to ask the same damn thing over and over again, but is this method you did better than what Bezos did? You seem to imply you wanted to improve upon his method with your comment on his reply.

Comment: @FelixMaldonado this method could (potentially) be upstreamed to be added to the default patterns so it worked out of the box, Javier's is slower but potentially more complete as someone could over-ride my answer with a value 9 forcing hyphenation trumping my value 8, short form: my answers are natuarally always the best;-)