# Wrong accents positioning (Russian, lualatex, Times New Roman)

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, accents, russian

Consider this minimal example. In the first line, the stress mark is on its right place. In the second, all accents are misplaced. Adding `\/` in random places in the third results in correct positions again. Commenting out `\setmainlanguage{russian}` also solves this issue. But what is the right way to do it?

(Font files are from Windows, I keep them in the working directory just for this project and load by files' names.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{TIMES.TTF}[
Renderer = Node,
BoldFont = TIMESBD.TTF,
ItalicFont = TIMESI.TTF,
BoldItalicFont = TIMESBI.TTF] 

\begin{document}

\textbf{СОБ\'{А}КА}

\textbf{КАЗ\'{А}К} \emph{каз\'{а}к} {каз\'{а}к}

\textbf{КА\/З\'{А}К} \emph{каз\'{а}\/к} {к\/аз\'{а}к}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709038/2388

Comment: Ah, thank you, Ulrike, I should have searched for similar questions better.  So it is `\patterns{8^^^^0301}` with `polyglossia`